# Expressing algorithmic problem as a mathematical problem

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, permutations, algorithms, sorting

I'm working in an algorithmic problem, which can surely be solved without any math involved, however I'm practicing (translating problems to formal definitions). I've done some baby steps however I need some expert help.

> **algorithmic problem:** 
>  Given Two stacks `a` and `b` , stack `a` contains some random amounts of numbers and stack
> `b` is empty. and given exactly `11` operations , sort the
> numbers with the lease amount of operations.
>
> ~ `sa`: swap the first 2 elements at the top of stack `a`.
> ~ `sb`: same as above for `b`.
>  ~ `ss`: `sa` and
> `sb` at the same time.
>  ~ `pa`: take the first element of
> `b` and put it at the top of `a`.
>  ~ `pb`: same as
> above for `b`.
>  ~ `ra`: shift up all elements of stack
> `a` by 1 The first element becomes the last one.
>  ~`rb`:
> same as above for `b`.
>  ~`rr`: `ra` and `rb` at the
> same time.
>  ~`rra`: shift down all elements of stack `a` by
> one The last element becomes the first one.
>
>  ~ `rrb`: same as above for `b`.
>  ~ `rrr` : `rra` and `rrb` at the
> same time.

one cannot compare without comparison and in the algorithmic problem its allowed because its not a movement per se, in algo problem you can compare what you're at, and you're arrive at what you're at by looping, so I thought lets just say

`cab`: compare any or all elements in `a` and `b` any time.

**my baby steps:**

- given a sequence $A$ of $n$ numbers $\left\langle a_{1}, a_{2},
     ...a_{n} \right\rangle $ and an empty sequence $B$. produce a
  permutations (reordering) of the input $\left\langle a_{1}, a_{2},
     ...a_{n} \right\rangle $ so that $\left\langle a_{1} \le  a_{2} \le
     a_{n} \right\rangle $

My main problem is how to formalize these operations (`sa`,`sb` ...) in math entities, one idea is functions, but  I'm not that good to complete the formalization. What do you think ?

Comment: Don't apologize for a long post, it's good to be thorough!